# Write Perl's system call output to a file

Tags: perl, file-descriptor

I'm trying to merge a Perl script's STDOUT and STDERR streams, and fork it off to a log file.

```
open( MERGED, "|-", "tee /tmp/my.log" );
*STDOUT = *MERGED;
*STDERR = *MERGED;

print  "1: print\n";
warn   "2: warn\n";
system "echo 3: system call";
```

In this example, the "print" and "warn" messages appear in both the terminal and the log, while the system call appears only in the terminal.

How can I split my output streams off to a log file?

Note: only needs to work in Unix, and I don't want rely on packages that aren't part of the standard Perl distribution (e.g. File::Tee, IO::Tee..).

Comment: `print qx(echo 3: backtiks)`

Comment: Is capturing/printing the output of my subprocesses the only way to achieve this? If the system call takes a while (and produces a lot of output) this isn't desirable; it'd be nice to have it flush and print in real-time, rather than collecting it all and printing it all at once.

Comment: Perhaps `open(my $sub, "-|", "echo 3" ); print while <$sub>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The child program knows nothing of Perl's variables. If you want to redirect a child's stdout, you'll need to redirect file descriptor 1.

```
open(my $MERGED, "|-", "tee", "/tmp/my.log") or die $!;
open(STDOUT, '>&', $MERGED) or die $!;
open(STDERR, '>&', $MERGED) or die $!;
```

Comment: This seems to work, but now the script doesn't exit properly. Is there some kind of cleanup I've got to do before it'll exit?

Comment: `close($MERGE);` or make `$MERGE` go out of scope.

Comment: Doesn't work... closing `STDOUT` and `STDERR` won't do it either.

Comment: Ahh the order is important.. close `STDOUT` and `STDERR` _first_ then close `$MERGED`.. Thanks!

Comment: oh right! `close($MERGED)` will close the handle and wait for `tee` to finish, which won't happen since STDOUT and STDERR are keeping the other end of the pipe open.

Comment: Uh oh.. is it possible to close the `tee` part way through execution, and open a new `tee` pointing to a different location?

Comment: Yeah, redirect STDOUT and STDERR as shown instead of using `close`

Comment: In this case, the original `tee` stays open, getting all of the "second" log info as well.

Comment: I guess there are several ways to do it.. see my answer

Comment: That leaves the original `tee` open.

Comment: If it's open, nothing gets written to it though.

Comment: That cause you don't send anything to it. But that's not important, because you implied you didn't want `tee` to stay open, and ending it is a good thing.

Comment: Looks like I just `close($ONE)` after the "unhook" section?

Comment: @ajwood, Yes, that's all

Answer (score 1):

FYI: Here is what I came up with based on ikegami's suggestion:

```
$| = 1;

# Hold on to the original handles
open(my $STDOUT_ORIG, '>&', \*STDOUT) or die $!;
open(my $STDERR_ORIG, '>&', \*STDERR) or die $!;

# Fork to log
open( my $ONE, "|-", "tee /tmp/my0.log" ) || die $!;
open( STDOUT, '>&', $ONE ) || die $!;
open( STDERR, '>&', $ONE ) || die $!;

# Make some noise
print  "1: print\n";
warn   "2: warn\n";
system "echo 3: system call";

# Unhook from the first `tee`
open( STDOUT, '>&', $STDOUT_ORIG ) || die $!;
open( STDERR, '>&', $STDERR_ORIG ) || die $!;
close($ONE);

# Fork to next log
open( my $TWO, "|-", "tee /tmp/my1.log" ) || die $!;
open( STDOUT, '>&', $TWO ) || die $!;
open( STDERR, '>&', $TWO ) || die $!;

print  "A: print\n";
warn   "B: warn\n";
system "echo C: system call";

close(STDERR);
close(STDOUT);
```